# как переключить видеокарту в лептопе

Tags: ubuntu

в лептопе lenovo встроено две видео карты intel_uhd_630 и nvidia_gf_1650 как я могу disable карту intel?
в винде есть диспетчер устройств и там есть пункт выключить устройство, как это сделать в ubuntu18?